# Adding a row to a gridview programmatically VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

VS 2013, VB. ASP.NET

I have a gridview on my page.

```
                     <asp:GridView ID="gvSteam" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gvSteam">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Generation" HeaderText="Steam Generation (Capacity)" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DisplayName" />

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TPH" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblValueEnergy" runat="server" Text='<%# Format8888(Eval("Power")) %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>


                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

The code behind is as follows

```
        Dim Asset As New Assets
    Dim Allsteam As New List(Of Assets)
    Allsteam = Asset.GetSteamGenerated()
    gvSteam.DataSource = Allsteam
    gvSteam.DataBind()
```

I want to add a blank row into the gridview at a certain point (for example after row 4) and add some text to it.

I can examples using data tables but I am using a gridview and would prefer to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it with the following, may not be the best way but it works.

```
        Dim newRow As GridViewRow

    For Each newRow In gvSteam.Rows

        If newRow.RowIndex = 3 Then

            Dim row As New GridViewRow(4, 4, DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal)
            Dim tc As New TableCell
            tc.ColumnSpan = 2
            Dim lbl As New Label
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl)
            lbl.Text = "Steam Turbine 11"
            row.Controls.Add(tc)
            gvSteam.Rows(4).Parent.Controls.AddAt(4, row)

        End If
    Next
```